# What is the fastest way to parse variable record binary files in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

## The Python Binary File Parsing Deep Dive

### Intro

I'm an electrical engineer by trade, however my job has a lot of software engineering overlap. Recently something I've been working on is a Python parser for a binary format that has a varying record format. The format is [STDF V4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Test_Data_Format), which is a binary format created by Teradyne for storing semi-conductor test data. My goal was to parse this data into a tabular format for data analysis/visualization (ideally CSV).

There are some existing libraries already in Python for parsing this format, however they are quite slow for any files >100MB. Specifically, I was using [pySTDF](https://github.com/cmars/pystdf). Rather than continue to mess with this rather complicated format, I decided to do a deep dive on general binary file parsing methods in Python.

This post will be divided into what research has told me thus far, an experiment I conducted on binary file parsing, and what answers I'm hoping the community can provide for me.

### Pre Experiment Research

I found two awesome posts that seem to directly address the root of my issue.

One post [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/117080/efficiently-processing-large-100-mb-structured-binary-data-in-python-3) on the code review portion of stack exchange addresses some methods to speed up binary file reads in Python3. When I dig into the source code for pySTDF, this post starts to highlight why this library is so slow. Although the library is very organized and "Pythonic" in nature, there are many, many nested classes and function calls that slow down parsing.

Another good post [here](http://rabexc.org/posts/io-performance-in-python) looks at file i/o performance in Python at a higher level. This post also brings things into clearer view. Python isn't neccessarily struggling with *reading* binary data from disk slowly, but rather when you're iterating on the order of millions of times every little function call, operation, etc. starts to really hurt you.

With all this in mind I decided to try out a couple of different general binary parsing libraries in Python and compare them in performance.

### The Experiment

I decided to compare performance for 3 different methods of parsing binary files for 3 different levels of complexity.

The methods are:

- [Construct Library](https://construct.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- [Kaitai Project](https://kaitai.io/)
- Homebrew (code I wrote for parsing with an emphasis on leanness)

For brevity's sake I won't get into describing the nitty gritty of how all these parser's work (including my own) but please see the github link [here](https://github.com/haydenridd/binary_parser_comparison) for full source code and refer to the links above for information on those parsers.

**File Generation**

To generate some test files, I used the Construct library to generate binary files of my own format.

First I wanted a simple binary file with a constant record length and format:

```py
# Simple tabular binary record with fixed fields
data_simple_fmt = Struct(
    "field1" / Int16ul,
    "field2" / Int8ul,
    "field3" / Float32l,
    "field4" / Int32sl
)
```

Diagram of format:

[image: Simple Data Diagram]

Next I wanted a format where it had a consistent number of fields, but had some fields that varied in length:

```py
# Simple tabular binary record with 2 varying string fields, a record length header is included
data_varying_fmt = Struct(
    "record_len" / Int16ul,
    "field1" / Int16ul,
    "field2" / Int8ul,
    "field3" / Int16ul,
    "field4" / PascalString(Int8ul, "utf8"),
    "field5" / PascalString(Int8ul, "utf8"),
    "field6" / Float32l
)
```

Diagram of format:
[image: Varying Data Diagram]

Finally, in the spirit of STDF, I wanted a format where there could be different record types depending on a record header:

```py
# Complex binary record with multiple tabular record types that have varying fields indicated by record header
table1_fmt = Struct(
    "table1_field1" / Int16ul,
    "table1_field2" / Int8ul,
    "table1_field3" / PascalString(Int8ul, "utf8"),
    "table1_field4" / Float32l
)
table2_fmt = Struct(
    "table2_field1" / PascalString(Int8ul, "utf8"),
    "table2_field2" / PascalString(Int8ul, "utf8"),
    "table2_field3" / PascalString(Int8ul, "utf8")
)
table3_fmt = Struct(
    "table3_field1" / Int16ul,
    "table3_field2" / Int32ul,
    "table3_field3" / Int32ul,
    "table3_field4" / Int32ul,
    "table3_field5" / Int32ul,
    "table3_field6" / Int32ul,
    "table3_field7" / Int32ul,
    "table3_field8" / Int32ul,
    "table3_field9" / PascalString(Int8ul, "utf8"),
    "table3_field10" / Float32l,
    "table3_field10" / Float32l
)

data_complex_fmt = Struct(
    "record_len" / Int16ul,
    "record_typ" / Int8ul,
    Switch(this.record_typ,
           {
               1: Embedded(table1_fmt),
               2: Embedded(table2_fmt),
               3: Embedded(table3_fmt)
           })
)
```

Diagram of format:
[image: Complex Data Diagram]

From here I coded a rather clunky script for generating 100 KB, 100 MB, and 1 GB files of each format with randomized data:

```py
import os
import random
import string

from construct_format_defs import data_simple_fmt, data_varying_fmt, data_complex_fmt

# generation switches
gen_simple = False
gen_varying = True
gen_complex = False

# output directory
output_dir = "./test_binary_files"

# file names
data_simple_fn = "data_simple"
data_varying_fn = "data_varying"
data_complex_fn = "data_complex"

# desired file sizes
file_size_small = 100*1024 # 100 kib
file_size_medium = 100*1024**2 # 100 mib
file_size_big = 1024**3 # 1 gib

for fname in [data_simple_fn, data_varying_fn, data_complex_fn]:

    if (fname in data_simple_fn and gen_simple) or (fname in data_varying_fn and gen_varying) or \
            (fname in data_complex_fn and gen_complex):

        # build each file type
        with open(os.path.join(output_dir, fname + "_small.bin"), "wb") as f_small, \
             open(os.path.join(output_dir, fname + "_medium.bin"), "wb") as f_medium, \
             open(os.path.join(output_dir, fname + "_large.bin"), "wb") as f_large:

            # initialize file size in bytes
            file_size = 0
            while file_size < file_size_big:

                # Create randomized dictionary
                if fname in data_simple_fn:
                    d_write = {
                        "field1": random.randint(0, 2**16-1),
                        "field2": random.randint(0, 2**8-1),
                        "field3": random.randint(0, 25 * 10000) / 10000,
                        "field4": random.randint(-(2**31), 2**31-1)
                    }
                    # write byte stream to files
                    bytes_data = data_simple_fmt.build(d_write)

                elif fname in data_varying_fn:
                    d_write = {
                        "field1": random.randint(0, 2**16-1),
                        "field2": random.randint(0, 2**8-1),
                        "field3": random.randint(0, 2**16-1),
                        "field4": ''.join(str(chr(random.choice(range(0, 128)))) for x in range(random.randint(1, 20))),
                        "field5": ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for x in range(random.randint(1, 20))),
                        "field6":  random.randint(-(2**31), 2**31-1)
                    }
                    # calculate what record length is with varying fields
                    d_write["record_len"] = 9 + len(d_write["field4"]) + len(d_write["field5"]) + 2
                    # write byte stream to files
                    bytes_data = data_varying_fmt.build(d_write)

                else:
                    d_write = {
                        "record_typ": random.randint(1, 3)
                    }
                    d_sub_write = {}
                    if d_write["record_typ"] == 1:
                        d_sub_write["table1_field1"] = random.randint(0, 2**16-1)
                        d_sub_write["table1_field2"] = random.randint(0, 2**8-1)
                        d_sub_write["table1_field3"] = ''.join(
                            str(chr(random.choice(range(0, 128)))) for x in range(random.randint(1, 20)))
                        d_sub_write["table1_field4"] = random.randint(-(2**31), 2**31-1)
                        d_write["record_len"] = len(d_sub_write["table1_field3"]) + 7 + 1

                    elif d_write["record_typ"] == 2:
                        d_sub_write["table2_field1"] = ''.join(
                            random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for x in range(random.randint(1, 20)))
                        d_sub_write["table2_field2"] = ''.join(
                            str(chr(random.choice(range(0, 128)))) for x in range(random.randint(1, 20)))
                        d_sub_write["table2_field3"] = ''.join(
                            str(chr(random.choice(range(0, 128)))) for x in range(random.randint(1, 20)))
                        d_write["record_len"] = len(d_sub_write["table2_field1"]) + len(d_sub_write["table2_field2"]) + len(
                            d_sub_write["table2_field3"]) + 3

                    else:
                        d_sub_write["table3_field1"] = random.randint(0, 2**16-1)
                        d_sub_write["table3_field2"] = random.randint(0, 2**32-1)
                        d_sub_write["table3_field3"] = random.randint(0, 2**32-1)
                        d_sub_write["table3_field4"] = random.randint(0, 2**32-1)
                        d_sub_write["table3_field5"] = random.randint(0, 2**32-1)
                        d_sub_write["table3_field6"] = random.randint(0, 2**32-1)
                        d_sub_write["table3_field7"] = random.randint(0, 2**32-1)
                        d_sub_write["table3_field8"] = random.randint(0, 2**32-1)
                        d_sub_write["table3_field9"] = ''.join(
                            random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for x in range(random.randint(1, 20)))
                        d_sub_write["table3_field10"] = random.randint(-(2**31), 2**31-1)
                        d_sub_write["table3_field11"] = random.randint(-(2**31), 2**31-1)
                        d_write["record_len"] = 38 + len(d_sub_write["table3_field9"]) + 1

                    d_write["sub_table"] = d_sub_write
                    # write byte stream to files
                    bytes_data = data_complex_fmt.build(d_write)

                # gate writing if we have surpassed desired file size
                if file_size < file_size_small:
                    f_small.write(bytes_data)
                if file_size < file_size_medium:
                    f_medium.write(bytes_data)
                f_large.write(bytes_data)

                # add bytes data to determine file size
                file_size += len(bytes_data)
```

**File Parsing**

Next I coded a test suite for timing the 3 different parsers. To keep things simple, the goal was to parse each of the 3 file formats into memory. I decided to skip the 1 GB file for now due to how long it takes.

The full test suite:

```py
import os
import time
import mmap
import struct

# CONSTRUCT IMPORTS
from construct import GreedyRange
from construct_format_defs import data_simple_fmt, data_varying_fmt, data_complex_fmt

# KAITAI IMPORTS/PARSERS
from kaitai_export_simple import DataSimple
from kaitai_export_varying import DataVarying
from kaitai_export_complex import DataComplex

## CONSTANTS

# test directory
test_dir = "./test_binary_files"

# file names
data_simple_fn = "data_simple"
data_varying_fn = "data_varying"
data_complex_fn = "data_complex"

# sizes
small_f = "_small.bin"
med_f = "_medium.bin"
big_f = "_large.bin"

## MY PARSERS
def parse_simple(bin_fh):


    # Can also use: Array.array or numpy from file read since this is fixed format

    # precompile struct object
    structobj = struct.Struct("<HBfi")

    # intialize return data (in memory for now)
    data_ls = []

    # Get size in bytes
    bin_fh.seek(0, 2)
    bytes_size = bin_fh.tell()

    # Go back to beginning
    bin_fh.seek(0)

    # iteratively get data
    data_ls.extend(structobj.unpack(bin_fh.read(11)) for _ in range(0, bytes_size, 11))

    # output
    return data_ls

def parse_varying(bin_fh):

    # precompile struct objects for fixed read
    structobj_start = struct.Struct("<HHBHB")
    structobj_len = struct.Struct("<B")
    structobj_end = struct.Struct("<f")

    # intialize return data (in memory for now)
    data_ls = []

    # Get size in bytes
    bin_fh.seek(0, 2)
    bytes_size = bin_fh.tell()

    # Go back to beginning
    bin_fh.seek(0)

    # iteratively get data
    curr_bytes = 0
    while curr_bytes < bytes_size:
        tp_start = structobj_start.unpack(bin_fh.read(8))
        curr_bytes += 8 + tp_start[0]

        # read entire rest of record at once instead of multiple reads
        rest_bytes = bin_fh.read(tp_start[0] - 6)
        str1_len = tp_start[4]
        tp_start = tp_start[0:4] + struct.unpack("<" + str(str1_len) + "s", rest_bytes[0:str1_len])
        str2_len = rest_bytes[str1_len]
        tp_start += struct.unpack("<" + str(str2_len) + "s", rest_bytes[str1_len + 1:str1_len + 1 + str2_len])
        data_ls.append(tp_start + structobj_end.unpack(rest_bytes[str1_len + 1 + str2_len:]))

    # output
    return data_ls

def parse_complex(bin_fh):

    # precompile struct objects for fixed read

    # header section
    structobj_header = struct.Struct("<HB")

    # data section
    structobj_subtable1_chunk1 = struct.Struct("<HBB")
    structobj_subtable1_chunk2 = struct.Struct("<f")
    structobj_subtable3_chunk1 = struct.Struct("<HLLLLLLLB")
    structobj_subtable3_chunk2 = struct.Struct("<ff")

    # intialize return data (in memory for now)
    data_ls = []

    # Get size in bytes
    bin_fh.seek(0, 2)
    bytes_size = bin_fh.tell()

    # Go back to beginning
    bin_fh.seek(0)

    # iteratively get data
    curr_bytes = 0
    while curr_bytes < bytes_size:

        # Header section of table
        data_tuple = structobj_header.unpack(bin_fh.read(3))
        curr_bytes += 3 + data_tuple[0]

        # read entire rest of record at once instead of multiple reads
        rest_bytes = bin_fh.read(data_tuple[0])
        bytes_counter = 0

        # sub table section
        if data_tuple[1] == 1:

            data_tuple += structobj_subtable1_chunk1.unpack(rest_bytes[bytes_counter:bytes_counter+4])
            bytes_counter += 4
            str1_len = data_tuple[4]
            data_tuple = data_tuple[0:4] + struct.unpack("<" + str(str1_len) + "s",
                                                         rest_bytes[bytes_counter:bytes_counter + str1_len])
            bytes_counter += str1_len
            data_tuple += structobj_subtable1_chunk2.unpack(rest_bytes[bytes_counter:bytes_counter+4])

        elif data_tuple[1] == 2:

            str1_len = rest_bytes[0]
            bytes_counter += 1
            data_tuple += struct.unpack("<" + str(str1_len) + "s",
                                                         rest_bytes[bytes_counter:bytes_counter + str1_len])
            bytes_counter += str1_len

            str1_len = rest_bytes[bytes_counter]
            bytes_counter += 1
            data_tuple += struct.unpack("<" + str(str1_len) + "s",
                                        rest_bytes[bytes_counter:bytes_counter + str1_len])
            bytes_counter += str1_len

            str1_len = rest_bytes[bytes_counter]
            bytes_counter += 1
            data_tuple += struct.unpack("<" + str(str1_len) + "s",
                                        rest_bytes[bytes_counter:bytes_counter + str1_len])
            bytes_counter += str1_len

        else:

            data_tuple += structobj_subtable3_chunk1.unpack(rest_bytes[bytes_counter:bytes_counter+31])
            bytes_counter += 31
            str1_len = rest_bytes[30]
            data_tuple = data_tuple[0:31] + struct.unpack("<" + str(str1_len) + "s",
                                        rest_bytes[bytes_counter:bytes_counter + str1_len])
            bytes_counter += str1_len
            data_tuple += structobj_subtable3_chunk2.unpack(rest_bytes[bytes_counter:])

        data_ls.append(data_tuple)

    # output
    return data_ls


def benchmark_parsers():
    ## CONSTRUCT PARSERS

    # construct parsers (for pre-compilation)
    construct_parser_simple = GreedyRange(data_simple_fmt)
    construct_parser_simple.compile()
    construct_parser_varying = GreedyRange(data_varying_fmt)
    construct_parser_varying.compile()
    construct_parser_complex = GreedyRange(data_complex_fmt)
    construct_parser_complex.compile()

    # benchmark how long it takes to parse each file in various parsing types
    for parse_type in ["construct",  "kaitai", "homebrew"]:
        for file_type in [data_simple_fn, data_varying_fn, data_complex_fn]:
            for file_size in [small_f, med_f]:#[small_f, med_f, big_f]:
                with open(os.path.join(test_dir, file_type + file_size), "rb") as f:
                    mem_f = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
                    t0 = time.time()
                    if "simple" in file_type:
                        if parse_type in "construct":
                            data = construct_parser_simple.parse_stream(mem_f)
                        elif parse_type in "kaitai":
                            data = DataSimple.from_io(mem_f)
                        else:
                            data = parse_simple(mem_f)
                    elif "varying" in file_type:
                        if parse_type in "construct":
                            data = construct_parser_varying.parse_stream(mem_f)
                        elif parse_type in "kaitai":
                            data = DataVarying.from_io(mem_f)
                        else:
                            data = parse_varying(mem_f)
                    else:
                        if parse_type in "construct":
                            data = construct_parser_complex.parse_stream(mem_f)
                        elif parse_type in "kaitai":
                            data = DataComplex.from_io(mem_f)
                        else:
                            data = parse_complex(mem_f)
                    t = time.time()
                    print(parse_type + ": " + file_type + file_size + ": " + str(t-t0))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    benchmark_parsers()
```

**Performance Analysis**

The results in increasing order of time (seconds):

- Homebrew:

  - small size (100 KB):

    - simple format: 0.004
    - varying format: 0.788
    - complex format: 0.3748
  - medium size (100 MB):

    - simple format: 3.706
    - varying format: 5.626
    - complex format: 5.965
- Kaitai

  - small size (100 KB):

    - simple format: 0.606
    - varying format: 0.028
    - complex format: 0.030
  - medium size (100 MB):

    - simple format: 40.580
    - varying format: 43.815
    - complex format: 46.839
- Construct:

  - small size (100 KB):

    - simple format: 0.252
    - varying format: 2.518
    - complex format:  1.343
  - medium size (100 MB):

    - simple format: 231.170
    - varying format: 107.381
    - complex format: 136.934

I realized too late that creating constant file sizes with varying formats maybe isn't the best way to test. You can see Construct really struggles with the most basic format as it has by far the highest number of records, and thus the most iteration operations.

### Conclusions and Questions

From my experiments I've concluded that there currently isn't a generic binary file parsing library that can beat pure Python coding from a speed perspective. The one exception I'll give is that in the case of having fixed record formatted binary files like in the "simple format" case, numpy has a method documented [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html) that can directly import a binary file into an array as long as the fields are of fixed length. This method is extremely fast as I believe it is C based.

This brings me to my questions for the software engineering community:

- Am I missing something obvious here or are my pure Python examples about the fastest I can get?
- Is there an obvious area to substitute functions coded in C that I can call from Python for a massive speed up?
- Is there a c-based Python library I just haven't found that can parse non-uniform binary files very quickly?

You might be saying "well ~6 seconds isn't too bad for your complex example", however when I applied this same methodology to code as lean an STDF parser as possible, I was still dealing with ~25 seconds for an 100 MB file which wasn't acceptable for my use case. Extremely interested to hear feedback from the community on this. At the end of the day I may just need to switch to a different language as a coworker and I were able to accomplish the same task in ~1 second using Golang.

### Github for Project

Please see my Github [here](https://github.com/haydenridd/binary_parser_comparison) for all the code described in this project.

Comment: Heh... I don't doubt that there are faster options. But, have you considered the possibility that python is just kinda slow!?? ... What format is the golang solution using? Is one of these solutions building full object instances and the other *not*? ... (Object construction is expensive, especially in python...) ..  what other differences are there? ... Other than [golang *being faster in general*](https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/fastest/go-python3.html)?

Comment: @svidgen Sadly even before I posted this I'd almost completely come to conclusion that Python is indeed just kind of slow. And in terms of solution differences, it's a little hard to compare but both solutions sought to be as "flat" as possible, with minimal object creation. I didn't personally code the Golang solution so I'm not as familiar with it but when I coded the Python solution I was pretty careful to minimize object creation, etc. per the advice in one of my research posts.